# Why doesn't AsyncUnaryCall<T> and others extend Task<T>?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, grpc

When working with gRPC in C#, asynchronous calls return `AsyncUnaryCall<T>` (for unary calls - of course, other calls have slightly different return types). However, `AsyncUnaryCall<T>` does not extend `Task<T>`. Therefore, common things you would ordinarily do with a `Task<T>` do not work with `AsyncUnaryCall<T>`. This includes:

- specifying the continuation policy (using `ConfigureAwait`)
- using helpers like `Task.WhenAny` and `Task.WhenAll`

The latter is biting me at the moment, since I want to kick off multiple gRPC calls and wait for them all to complete. It seems my only recourse is to write a little helper that awaits for one after the other.

Why doesn't `AsyncUnaryCall<T>` mirror the functionality in `Task<T>`?

Comment: It [looks like](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/csharp/Grpc.Core/AsyncUnaryCall.cs) it exposes separate `Task`s for it's headers and the full response (see `ResponseAsync` and `ResponseHeadersAsync`). Why aren't those sufficient?

Comment: You not necessarily need Task to apply await stuff, the type only needs to implement awaitable/awaiter pattern which AsyncUnaryCall does.

Comment: You can pass in `call.ResponseAsync`. Or, for several: `await Task.WhenAll(calls.Select(x => x.ResponseAsync));`

Comment: Nice, somehow I missed that when spelunking the API. Thanks.

Comment: One thing that's still no clear to me is whether I should be dereferencing `ResponseAsync` for every call I make so that I can `ConfigureAwait(false)` on it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As I said in a comment, whilst it's "Task-like", it actually [represents two separate `Task`s](https://grpc.io/grpc/csharp/api/Grpc.Core.AsyncUnaryCall-1.html). If you want to work with the individual `Task`s *as* `Task`s, just access the appropriate property (e.g. `ResponseHeadersAsync` or `ResponseAsync`).

If you have a variable `themAll` of type `List<AsyncUnaryCall<T>>` then using `WhenAll`/`WhenAny` is easy:

```
await Task.WhenAny(themAll.Select(c=>c.ResponseHeadersAsync));
```

if you've got useful work you can do when any headers arrive, or

```
await Task.WhenAll(themAll.Select(c=>c.ResponseAsync));
```

if you can't do anything useful until they're all completed. As two examples. Similarly, you can extract one of these tasks and use it in an `await` with a `ConfigureAwait`, if you want to do so.

Comment: I'm interested in exploring the `WhenAny` of numerious gRPC streams.  Is there a reliable example of handling multiple streams in one thread where whichever stream produces data is handled as soon as possible?  In addition to that, what happens to the state of the other streams after returning from `Task.WhenAny(...)`